# Почему я не могу задать минимальную высоту в GUI.BOX

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я хочу сделать полоску над врагом, получается вот это:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему Gui.Box не принимает высоту текстуры? Вот скрипт:

```
private void OnGUI()
    {
        if (isStripLife) {
            float relStripPos = HelperConst.valueFromProcent(health, maxHealth, maxStripHealth);
            Vector3 posScr = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position);
            GUI.Box(new Rect(posScr.x - biasStripX, Screen.height - posScr.y - biasStripY, maxStripHealth, 2), healthTex0);
            GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(posScr.x - biasStripX, Screen.height - posScr.y - biasStripY, relStripPos, 2), healthTex);
        }   
    }
```

В  healthTex0 добавлена текстура UI MASK, в  healthTex красная текстура, если GUI.Box в последний параметр передать "" то ничего не изменится. Как выйти из сложившийся ситуации?

Answer (score 0):

Короче, я не хочу сказать что это решение проблемы скорее костыль но т.к. никто ничего мне не написал, напишу это. Я вобще убрал GUI.Box вместо этого нарисовал текстуру темже способом что и первую, но черного цвета, получилось так себе но все же лучше чем просто исчезает красная полоса:

```
  private void OnGUI()
    {
        if (isStripLife) {
            float relStripPos = HelperConst.valueFromProcent(health, maxHealth, maxStripHealth);
            Vector3 posScr = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position);
            // GUI.Box(new Rect(posScr.x - biasStripX, Screen.height - posScr.y - biasStripY, maxStripHealth, 2), healthTex0);
            GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(posScr.x - biasStripX, Screen.height - posScr.y - biasStripY, maxStripHealth, 2), healthTex0);
            GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(posScr.x - biasStripX, Screen.height - posScr.y - biasStripY, relStripPos, 2), healthTex);
        }   
    }
```

Comment: А почему бы не попробовать хелс-бары реализовать в `Canvas` (`RenderMode` = `WorldSpace`) в виде `Image` (c `ImageType` = `Filled`). По необходимости меняете процент заполнения спрайта-прогрессбара, а каждый кадр позиционируете по Мировым координатам над нужными объектами и поворачиваете хелс-бары "лицом" к камере?